# Why do some methods work with inject and some won't?

Tags: ruby

I understand that I can pass a method to `inject`. For instance,

```
[1,2,3].inject(:+)     #=> 6
```

but this one throws

```
["1","2","3"].inject(:to_i) #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
["1","2","3"].inject(:to_s) #=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

I am not doing anything particular, just trying to get my basics right.

Comment: In most real-world situations, you need `map` instead of `inject`, e.g. `["1","2","3"].map(&:to_i) #=> [1,2,3]`.

Comment: True. This was an initial step before I wanted to perform a sum, i.e. convert to `to_i` and use `inject` to sum it.

Comment: I would do both steps at the same time: `['1','2','3'].reduce(0){|sum, n| sum + n.to_i}` (note that `reduce` is an alias for `inject`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short explanation is "the callback for `inject` has to take two arguments." But that probably won't clear it up entirely.

OK, so let's look at the normal block form of inject:

```
[1, 2, 3].inject {|memo, number| memo + number}
```

Passing a symbol works the same way — it just turns the symbol into a proc that takes the place of the block. When you turn a symbol into a proc, the conversion looks like this:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    proc {|receiver, *args| receiver.send(self, *args) }
  end
end
```

So when you pass `:+`, it calls the `+` method of the memo value with the current number as the argument, just  like `1 + 2`.

So when you pass `:to_i`, it's equivalent to this:

```
["1", "2", "3"].inject {|memo, number_string| memo.to_i(number_string) }
```

But that doesn't make any sense. You're trying to pass the string as an argument to `to_i`. which is invalid.

Comment: Good answer.  A small detail that may be of interest to someone: in Chuck's penultimate line, because `inject` is not given an argument, `memo` is initially assigned the first element of the array (`"1"`), so the exception occurs when Ruby encounters `"1".to_i("2")`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland upvoted your comment for the use of "penultimate" :)

Comment: Thanks, @Mark, I use the term at every opportunity.  Sometimes it's just an excuse for a comment.  Perhaps I should have instead referred to Chuck's mention of "equivalent" in his antepenultimate line.